# Php convert ldap YMD timestamps into appropriate date format

Tags: php, ldap

Iam learning php these days. I've one small task to convert ldap YMD timestamps into appropriate date format.

I am using below code to conevert, but logic seems wrong. Here is the code:

```
<?php
function convertLdapTimeStamp($timestamp){
        //PHP script to convert a timestamp returned from an LDAP query into a Unix timestamp 
        // The date as returned by LDAP in format yyyymmddhhmmsst
        $date = $timestamp;

        // Get the individual date segments by splitting up the LDAP date
        $year = substr($date,0,4);
        $month = substr($date,4,2);
        $day = substr($date,6,2);
        $hour = substr($date,8,2);
        $minute = substr($date,10,2);
        $second = substr($date,12,2);

        // Make the Unix timestamp from the individual parts
        $timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

        // Output the finished timestamp
        return $month."/".$day."/".$year." ".$hour.":".$minute.":".$second;
    }


convertLdapTimeStamp(20190630175050Z);

?>
```

For the input: '20190630175050Z', Output should be : 30 Jun, 2019 11:20:50 PM IST.

Please tell me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old... but !
Your code seems to work fine for me, here is the function I use now (based on yours) with default date format :

```
function ldap_dt($date, $format = 'd.m.Y H:i:s') {

    // Get the individual date segments by splitting up the LDAP date
    $y = substr($date,0,4);
    $m = substr($date,4,2);
    $d = substr($date,6,2);
    $h = substr($date,8,2);
    $i = substr($date,10,2);
    $s = substr($date,12,2);

    // Make the Unix timestamp from the individual parts
    $timestamp = mktime($h, $i, $s, $m, $d, $y);

    // Output the 'never' for 01.01.1970 01:00, 30.11.1999 00:00, or after now
    if($timestamp == 0 || $timestamp == 943916400 || $timestamp > time())
        return 'never';

    // Output the finished timestamp
    return date($format, $timestamp);
}
```

Examples of use :

```
echo ldap_dt($date);                   // default date format defined in function
echo ldap_dt($date, 'm/d/Y H:i:s');    // custom date format
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me, thank you. I tried a hold bunch of other tricks where they try to convert from an epoche time, none of them work.  Tested in php 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

To convert from a non-string to string:

```
$date = settype($timestamp,'string');
```

**end of update**

---

This works and is tested.

### Test Code:

```
$time = strtotime('20190630175050Z');  convert string to time
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s A T',$time);
```

### Result:

```
30 Jun, 2019 13:06:50 PM EDT
```

Comment: But 20190630175050Z is not a String in my case. How do I convert that number to a string? I tried using strval but getting errors.

Comment: see my new update, I thought the timestamp ended in a character:  yyyymmddhhmmsst  where t is time zone.

Comment: I have tried your code here: https://ideone.com/4gcj3f Everything is fine, but minutes showing wrong value. I am comparing your value with this site: http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php

Comment: It was a typo.  Change `H:m:s` to `H:i:s`